# If everything is predetermined, why should I feel motivated to do anything?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind, determinism

I am a proponent of [hard-determinism](https://youtu.be/vCGtkDzELAI).

Now, the problem is, if free will doesn't exist, why should I feel motivated to do anything? The question "Why should I feel motivated to do anything" is a bit different than the question "Why should I do anything at all" in that I don't think no one will actually just sit in a chair and do nothing basically, so asking the second question is meaningless.

However, the first question, the one that I'm asking, is more meaningful in my opinion. Even if I'm going through the motions of the day, I won't be motivated. And you need motivation to succeed, badly. Since valuable resources are limited, only the most motivated and capable individuals will get access to them.

(Context: I will be sitting for entrance exams to public universities (where studying is essentially free) in a few months, where I will be competing with thousands of students, and the number of seats is extremely limited, and I don't have the money to afford a degree in a private university)

So, as a proponent of hard determinism, how can I get the necessary motivation that I need?

Comment: Do you think that hard-determinism will provide you "automatically" with a monthly wage?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, hard-determinism will not provide me automatically with a monthly wage. However, if I were to get free monthly wages in the future, then it has already been carved in stone by determinism; I don't have any free will here and I can't change anything for better or worse. So, where will I get the burning motivation from, which I desperately need for success?

Comment: The question has no sense: it is you that is proposing a position that has no logical justification, yet you are asking for a justification.

Comment: Your concern is perfectly clear: if the future is "already there", sit and wait. If it is "written" that your wage will arrive regardless of your effort, no reason to move, and if the wage will not arrive despite your effort, they are useless.

Comment: if everything is predetermined, you don't get a choice about whether you feel motivated; that too is predetermined. if you have a choice, then nothing is predetermined.

Comment: I would like to add: it appears (to me at least) that there is a subtle, though possibly valuable, distinction between the claim that "one would feel (un)motivated *because* it has been predetermined", versus the claim that "it *is predetermined that* one out would feel (un)motivated because of other reasons".

Comment: Agent's free will is really about *choice* of the *necessary* mode which can only be viewed as hard determinism without any modality only from perhaps God's point of view. Notice in English a sentence of future tense such as "Something will happen." contains the word *will*, so tense in this sense is nothing but a will possessed and manifested by something...

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/96034/what-motivates-children-to-start-walking/96407#96407, perhaps a more ignorant beings prespective would answer oyour Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of your comments suggests a thread to pull on:

> "if I were to get free monthly wages in the future, then it has already been carved in stone by determinism.... So, where will I get the burning motivation from, which I desperately need for success?"

That phrasing suggests that you view determinism as independent of your motivation.  And yet your question *strongly* implies you believe motivation has an impact on your success.   Thus they must come together.  Hard determinism does not say that you can slice up the system, such as removing your motivation from the equation, and presume that the resulting physical world's behavior is independent from that removed segment.  [Gestalt theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology) is a formal attempt to explore this.  Their tag line is "The whole is different from the sum of its parts."

Now from a hard deterministic point of view, the answer to this is that you will either be motivated or not.  It also implies that, if you will be motivated and motivation takes some effort, you will put in that effort.
So from a proponent of hard determinism, the question is moot.  You will either do the correct set of actions it takes to be motivated if you will be motivated, or you will take another set of actions if you will not be motivated.

Which leads to a rather funny question: what is "motivation?"  I mean, in plain English it is a well understood word, but what is it in a hard-deterministic mindset?  It must be part of that deterministic system, must it not?  It's an oddly self-referential concept, when you dig into it.  These self-referential bits are what make it really difficult to argue the "sit on my rear and do nothing, and it will all come to me" arguments.  They're just tricky enough to leave an itch to be scratched.  And that makes for rather fun hard deterministic arguments.

From a personal perspective, one recommendation I would have is to look at the Eastern concept of the [dao(道)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao).  It is a philosophy which is very compatible with hard-determinism, especially if the Great Dao/Eternal Dao is the only true dao there is.  And yet, it has a long history of motivating people.  Little ol' me may not be able to cold-call who you are and force you into having motivation in a single stack exchange answer.  But several thousand years of accrued wisdom from philosophers may have a think or two for you.

Of course, by asking this question, it appears you seek a kick in the rear quote to get you jumping up and doing what you know you should be doing.  That's hard to come by from a huge body of philosophy, so I'll offer a quote.  This is from "Illusions" by Richard Bach, and I have to remind myself of it from time to time:

> "Argue hard enough for your limitations, and they're yours."

Answer (score 2):

> So, as a proponent of hard determinism, how can I get the necessary motivation that I need?

Several possibilities come to mind:

1. You could wake up to tomorrow and suddenly feel motivated for no apparent reason. Feelings and behaviors constantly change without our conscious understanding.
2. Something external could happen that leads to a conscious change in your perspective. This could be as simple as some encouraging words from someone.
3. You could identify the reason you lack motivation, and then act to change that condition. For example you might consciously embrace a [growth mindset](https://hbr.org/2016/01/what-having-a-growth-mindset-actually-means) and find motivation in that.

All that hard determinism means is that whether or not any of these things will happen is determined by prior causes. It doesn't mean they won't happen or that you won't experience the illusion of free will that is inherent to human consciousness. Beyond the philosophical question, if you're feeling distress about your lack of motivation and seeking advice, I would say you should focus your attention on possibility #3.

Answer (score 2):

Hard determinism means that nothing you feel, know, believe, want, fear, plan or prefer has no effect whatsoever on what you will *do*. All your actions are physically caused by prior events, they are all spinal reflexes. There is no need or use for any kind of mental processing, no need for a brain. There is no mental processing of information.

It is logically impossible to combine a belief in hard determinism and a feeling of motivation. You cannot have both, you have to pick one. And luckily you don't have a choice.

It is also logically impossible to *believe* in hard determinism. There is no *concept* of belief in hard determinism. You simply cannot believe that you cannot believe anything.

You are free to search and wish for motivation, just don't let any illogical beliefs get in your way.

Comment: "It is logically impossible to combine a belief in hard determinism and a feeling of motivation." - I disagree completely with this statement. A hard determinist experiences the feeling of motivation while understanding the feeling to be misleading.

Comment: There are no experiences in determinism. No feelings. No motivation. No understanding. Nothing misleading.  Nothing mental. Only physical events.

Answer (score 1):

> If everything is predetermined, why should I feel motivated to do anything?

If everything is predetermined, then how you feel about anything is also predetermined, and so, too, whether you feel motivated to act or not, whatever you eventually do.

Nobody abstains from doing anything on the ground that the future is predetermined. It is simply self-evident that what we do does change both the present and the future.

People who are not motivated to do anything are not motivated by the belief that the future is predetermined but because they don't know what to do to obtain what they want.